# How to test list of proxy servers?

Tags: proxy, test

I have list of HTTP/HTTPS/Socks proxy servers like this:

```
1.2.3.4:80  
5.6.7.8:8080  
...
```

I need to test each server if it works and if it is anonymous or not. I plan to put these servers to my webbrowser proxy settings.

When i was preparing to answer, i found this:

[Proxy Tester and WPAD Generator](https://sourceforge.net/projects/proxytest/)

It basically do what i want to do. It tests lists of proxies for anonymity. So i guess the question now is, are there other similar apps which would be better than this app? Thanks again

Comment: For each kind of proxies (http, https, socks), define first a manual test procedure (by changing the settings of your own browser). Once done, tell us your procedure and we may help you make this automatic with tools like `wget` or `curl`

Answer (score 4):

Untested:

```
cat proxylist | parallel --tag curl --proxy {} -o /dev/null --silent --head --write-out  '%{http_code}' http://www.fsf.org/ --max-time 5
```

Should give:

```
proxy:port    200
```

if the proxy works.

Comment: Nice reply! Great tool, didn't know this one!

Answer (score 0):

ProxySampler is a golang CLI tool for testing lists of proxies: https://github.com/packetstream/proxysampler

`proxysampler --output json --file ./proxies.txt --endpoint https://ifconfig.co/json --include-response-body`

```
{
  "success": 3,
  "fail": 0,
  "average_ttfb": 693,
  "results": [
    {
      "proxy": "https://proxyuser:proxypass_country-US@proxy.packetstream.io:31111",
      "endpoint": "https://ifconfig.co/json",
      "status_code": 200,
            "response_body": "{\"ip\":\"47.149.139.253\",\"ip_decimal\":798329853,\"country\":\"United States\",\"country_eu\":false,\"country_iso\":\"US\",\"city\":\"Torrance\",\"latitude\":33.846,\"longitude\":-118.3456,\"asn\":\"AS5650\",\"asn_org\":\"Frontier Communications of America, Inc.\"}",
      "latency": {
        "ttfb": 552,
        "connect": 29,
        "tls_handshake": 141
      },
      "error": null
    },
    {
      "proxy": "https://proxyuser:proxypass_country-US@proxy.packetstream.io:31111",
      "endpoint": "https://ifconfig.co/json",
      "status_code": 200,
      "response_body": "{\"ip\":\"63.237.69.254\",\"ip_decimal\":1072514558,\"country\":\"United States\",\"country_eu\":false,\"country_iso\":\"US\",\"city\":\"Walkersville\",\"hostname\":\"ssl.clarkconstruction.com\",\"latitude\":39.4787,\"longitude\":-77.3484,\"asn\":\"AS16431\",\"asn_org\":\"The Clark Construction Group, Inc.\"}",
      "latency": {
        "ttfb": 534,
        "connect": 28,
        "tls_handshake": 114
      },
      "error": null
    },
    {
      "proxy": "https://proxyuser:proxypass_country-US@proxy.packetstream.io:31111",
      "endpoint": "https://ifconfig.co/json",
      "status_code": 200,
      "response_body": "{\"ip\":\"24.167.234.46\",\"ip_decimal\":413657646,\"country\":\"United States\",\"country_eu\":false,\"country_iso\":\"US\",\"city\":\"Milwaukee\",\"hostname\":\"cpe-24-167-234-46.wi.res.rr.com\",\"latitude\":43.1166,\"longitude\":-87.9904,\"asn\":\"AS10796\",\"asn_org\":\"Charter Communications Inc\"}",
      "latency": {
        "ttfb": 993,
        "connect": 27,
        "tls_handshake": 272
      },
      "error": null
    }
  ]
}
```